# SQL Server Comparing INT from DATEDIFF does not work like I expected

Tags: sql-server, datediff

In my sub query I have this line in my Select stmt to do the DATEDIFF:

`DATEDIFF(day,[Invoice_Date], '2015-02-27 00:00:00.000') AS Days_AGED,`

In my main query to use that INT or Number returned, I have the code below in my select stmt to test:

```
(Days_AGED + 5) AS TEST_AGE, --This worked and gave me the correct number when 5 was added to the variable Days_AGED
    CASE
      WHEN (CAST(Days_AGED AS NUMERIC(10,0)) >= CAST(30 AS NUMERIC(10,0))) THEN CAST(Days_AGED AS VARCHAR(5)) + ' 0-30 Days' -- This worked when the number was 30 or a large number
      WHEN (Days_AGED >= 31 AND Days_AGED <= 60) THEN '31-60 Days'
      WHEN (Days_AGED >= 61 AND Days_AGED <= 90) THEN '61-90 Days'
      WHEN (Days_AGED >= 91 AND Days_AGED <= 120) THEN '91-120 Days'
      WHEN (Days_AGED >= 121 AND Days_AGED <= 150) THEN '121-150 Days'
      ELSE '151+ Days'
    END AS AGED_GRP
```

-- It seems as if the number was between 15 and 29 it would returned "151+ Days", This and "0-30" seems like the only returned outcome.

If I am able to add 5 to that INT value in the 1st WHEN, why can I not get it to evalute it correctly?

I just want it to be a number where the evaluation in my CASE stmt so I get the correct outcome. Thanks in advance for you help.

Comment: First `WHEN` should use ` <= ` instead of ` >= `.Why you have used `CAST(... AS NUMERIC ...)` ? `Days_AGED` is a text column ? If you want  to 30 to be considered numeric / decimal then you could use `30.`.

Comment: Your first `WHEN` for 0 to 30 is checking `>= 30`.  chanve to  `<= 30`

Comment: Duh, ok its my operator thats wrong.. Thanks guys!!